# populate usercontrol thru jquery

Tags: jquery, user-controls

I am trying to populate the textbox inside a usercontrol with value from the aspx which embedds this usercontrol, but it's giving error
') expected' !!

```
$("#<%=ucCode:txtCodename.ClientID %>").val(myCode[8]);
```

what is the correct way of populating a usercontrol with value in jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok.
 This is what worked for me so posting it in case it helps anyone else

```
$('#<%= ucCode.FindControl("txtCodename").ClientID %>').val(myCode);
```

cheers

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you are specifying the user control and a colon if you are doing this inside the user control itself.  Have you tried the following?

```
$("#<%= txtCodename.ClientID %>").val(myCode[8]);
```

Btw, I'd opt to replace the hard-coded 8 with a variable.  :)

Comment: Sorry If I confused you am trying to do this on the page which embedds usercontrol

Comment: First make sure you are actually retrieving the ID properly.  Other than that, i see nothing wrong with the script part of it.

Comment: that's the issue, is usercontrol:textbox is not the correct way of accessing it from the page embedding UC? the UC and the textbox ids are correct.

Comment: Create a public property on the user control that exposes the control id.  Then from the page, you can access said id.

Comment: I am able to trap the id on page for other things but fails when i try to set value of textbox inside it .